# Strip URL - PHP or .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have two pages on my site

- `http://www.strictlyrandl.com/strictly-reading-festival/`
- `http://www.strictlyrandl.com/strictly-leeds-festival/`

I used to have

- `http://www.strictlyreading.co.uk`
- `http://www.strictlyleeds.co.uk`

I did a redirect with my registrar so `strictlyreading.co.uk` would go to the relevant page on `strictlyrandl.com` and similar with Leeds.

However when someone goes to something like `strictlyreading.co.uk/page-name` they get redirected to `strictlyrandl.com/strictly-reading-festival/page-name` rather than just `strictlyrandl.com/strictly-reading-festival`

Is this best done using .htaccess or PHP? Any example would be great It has to be done at `strictlyrandl.com`

Comment: .htaccess with rewrite rules.  what are you currently using to do the redirect?

Comment: add more information on how the current redirects are being implemented.

Answer (score 0):

use a .htaccess rewrite rule
`RewriteRule (.*) http://www.strictlyrandl.com/strictly-reading-festival/$1 [R=301,L]`

Comment: Don't forget this line before your rewrite rule : RewriteEngine On

Comment: I refrained from downvoting because the question isn't that great. Props for trying though.